# Set command output as variable

Tags: batch-file, netstat

I have Batch code like this

```
@echo off
:begin
SET d=netstat -an | find /c "0.0.0.0:80"
rem echo %d%
if %%d == "2" (
    echo true

    pause

    rem exit

) else ( 
    echo false

    pause

    rem GOTO begin
)
```

I want make netstat stetment output stored in variable d, and d became parameter from If cluse, What wrong with my file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set a variable in your case.

This should work :

```
netstat -an | find /c "0.0.0.0:80" && echo true || echo False
```

But if you need to have this value in a variable you can do like this :

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('netstat -an ^| find /c "0.0.0.0:80"') do set D=%%a
if %D% equ 2 (
echo true
) else (
echo false)
```